# Value is not a member of type parameter

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass

I am trying to call method `bark` of `Dog` in an implicit implementation method, however I am getting

> def speak[Dog](dog: Dog): String = dog.bark
> ^
> On line 16: error: value bark is not a member of type parameter Dog

Here is my code

```scala
// Define class/type
case class Dog(val breed: String) {
    val bark: String = s"Bark!! I am a $breed"
}

// Define interface
trait Speakable[A] {
    def speak[A](animal: A): String
}

// Define interface companion object, where we can provide
//  implicit implementation methods 
object Speakable {
    def speak[A](animal: A)(implicit sp: Speakable[A]) = sp.speak(animal)
    implicit val dogSpeak: Speakable[Dog] = new Speakable[Dog] {
        def speak[Dog](dog: Dog): String = dog.bark
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `[Dog]` is simply a random type parameter. It could be anything. Remove it so you're not hiding the case class `Dog`

Comment: You're also hiding `Speakable`'s type parameter `A` in `speak` by defining another type parameter `A` given to the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type class doesn't need extra type parameter `A`

```
trait Speakable[A] {
  def speak(animal: A): String
}
```

(when you defined such type parameter `A` of the method it hid the type parameter `A` of the trait).

And then the instance

```
implicit val dogSpeak: Speakable[Dog] = new Speakable[Dog] {
  def speak(dog: Dog): String = dog.bark
}
```

also doesn't need type parameter of the method (when you defined such type parameter `Dog` you didn't use your class `Dog`, you defined new type hiding the class).